# Cannot access facebook group through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

[image]

I'm making use of facebook's [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=POST&path=207998293342051%2Ffeed&version=v3.0&message=foobar) in an attempt to automate a weekly post to a group. My attempts always meet with the response:

> Unsupported post request. Object with ID '207998293342051' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

This is puzzling. [Group 207998293342051](https://www.facebook.com/groups/207998293342051/) is one that I created myself for testing this functionality. And when generating the User Access Token in the Graph API Explorer, I tick the `publish_to_groups` permission.

Am I missing anything here? I have tried to `GET` the feed as well, but the response is the same.

[image]

Comment: You need `user_managed_groups` to be able to read the groups the user is an admin of to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe : thanks, but I get the same error even when I add `user_managed_groups` to the ticked boxes when requesting a new access token. In fact, I have ticked **all** of the boxes in the "Events, Groups & Pages" section and gotten only the same response.

Comment: Looks like this is currently still buggy, https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1673926572701574/